# Font size of the slds-page-header title

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, slds

With the help of the Page Header Component Blueprint I created an LWC that mimics the design of a standard related list. The only diference is, that the text of the Page Header Title is just slightly to big.
I already tryed slds-text-heading_large but that is to small, even when using `<b><b>`
This is the HTML for the title in the header:

```
<div class="slds-media__body">
    <div class="slds-page-header__name">
        <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
            <h1>
                <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="Aktuelle Vertragsinhalte (Produkte)">Aktueller Vertragsinhalt (Produkte)</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is the some other way to change the text size?